# External HD Ubuntu on old PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm trying to get my old HP pc to boot my external HD Ubuntu install.

[image: External HD Partition Table]

The PC boots in BIOS.

Can anyone see any obvious problems with how I have this partition table setup?

It's a PC from around 2006.
The internal HD currently runs Lubuntu.

Ideally I would love to have an Ubuntu install on my external drive that works with modern computers as well as this old one.

There are a lot of tutorials related to this online but no definitive answers.

Comment: No obvious problems but it is a UEFI mode installation - probably - beacuse it has an EFI partition. It won't boot in BIOS only computers.

Comment: Right. So basically need a seperate Ubuntu install on another drive if I want to use it on this old computer.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the drive is GPT then a small partition for the old bootloader can be created and then it should boot in any system. But of course that should have been done before actually installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Since you're booting it in BIOS mode, do you have a MBR on the drive?   The MBR cannot be in a partition (as a GPT/MBR compatible partition scheme will not use that space; space is allocated beyond MBR so as to not clobber it). If your intention for sdb1 was to provide the MBR; you've misunderstood what MBR is; the first 512 bytes of disk surface).  Does your old HP boot from the drive; some old dell/hp models will only boot if a single drive/memory device is plugged in (no capacity in BIOS to ask which to boot) so if another USB device has ram/rom/storage available none will boot.

Comment: No idea. Those partitions were automatically created for me when I installed Ubuntu. Will keep Googling.

Comment: Your partition setup looks like it should work with either a gpt or msdos partitioned disk, but your old computer may boot only msdos disks.  A legacy/BIOS install should work, avoiding the launchpad bug 1396379 for UEFI systems.

Comment: You can use the advice in [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS), and the simple solution with a pre-installed image or make the system yourself along the guidelines of [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312). Please be aware that some 'middle-aged' HP computers refuse to boot in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) via grub when there is a GUID partition table (GPT), but they are willing to boot when there is an MSDOS partition table (as indicated by ubfan1).

Comment: There are also good instructions by @C.S.Cameron at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1343838/installing-ubuntu-20-04-to-a-usb-pen-drive-256-gb-with-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: Followed these instructions by @C.S.Cameron multiple times but still boots into Lubuntu (on main drive) and never see Ubuntu install.